# Linux Reset adapter

Tags: linux, networking, nic, eth0

I have centos 7.3, and get these errors, why is this

```
[  888.884795] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[  890.923975] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 1130.843338] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[ 1132.882125] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 1362.726947] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[ 1364.787321] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 1594.102238] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <1d>
  TDT                  <23>
  next_to_use          <23>
  next_to_clean        <1b>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <10013a97b>
  next_to_watch        <1c>
  jiffies              <10013bf83>
  next_to_watch.status <1>
[ 1609.595390] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[ 1611.658749] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 1851.476553] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[ 1853.538042] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 2088.364430] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: Reset adapter
[ 2090.427674] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a virtual machine, might need to change the network adapter type of the interfaces.  Please see the related Serverfault Q&A [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/575571/virtualbox-vm-network-hangs-due-to-ethernet-reset-adapter)